# Drawing text with C++ directx

Tags: c++, text, directx

I'm creating an application overlay via Direct3D hooking, however I can't draw any text. I've started with [this sample](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=359794). The library itself seems to replace all D3D calls with own functions (and in the end it calls the original ones). I've tried all variations of `DrawText` without any result visible result. On the other hand, I can draw primitives with `DrawPrimitiveUP`. Also, the `DrawText(A)` defined in winuser.h only takes 5 arguments and it's completely missing font / color mentioned in all tutorials and forums. Am I doing something wrong?

```
DrawText(NULL, "text", -1, &rct, DT_NOCLIP|DT_SINGLELINE);
```

where `&rct` is my rectangle created before. I'm calling it directly in a child class of `IDirect3DDevice9`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The winuser.h DrawText is for GDI and uses the DC's currently selected font and text color etc., hence why it doesn't appear in the argument list.

Comment: @Logan That means I'm supposed to set it before to the device? It looks like I'm missing D3DXCreateFont in the hooked api.

Comment: GDI is separate from Direct3D, I don't think you want to use that DrawText at all (at least not directly), I really don't know much about Direct3D, hence why that was just a comment and not an answer.

It looks like you want to call D3DXCreateFont and then call DrawText on the resultant ID3DXFont instance. `D3DXCreateFont(..., &pFont); pFont->DrawText(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong DrawText function (GDI). Try using the one from ID3DXFont. (after creating the font,etc..)

Comment: Thanks, this is something that I didn't expected. I understand I can obtain font from the D3DXCreateFont, yet I don't have this method in the IDirect3DDevice9. MSDN does not say where it should be located http://bit.ly/9kv6Yg.

Comment: D3DXCreateFont is a stand alone function, not a method.

Comment: @Mikulas Like I said, the function is part of the ID3DXFont interface. http://bit.ly/d9cFN8. There could be a bug in the documentation you're using thats misleading you, maybe you can link us to a small piece of sample code that exhibits the problem..

Comment: Thank you, I've already managed to fix it. It indeed was GDI vs D3D problem.